# Python error when using "not in" in a if statement?

Tags: python

The aim is to remove vowels from the input

My code

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  av=[]
  for t in range(len(text)):
    if t not in "aeiouAEIOU":
      av.append(text[t])
  print "".join(av)
anti_vowel("Hey You!")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prog.py", line 7, in <module>
File "prog.py", line 4, in anti_vowel
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Please give a reason why this was not working

Comment: You just want `for t in text:`, which will iterate over the characters of `text`.

Comment: Adding `print t` would have revealed the problem to you in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the value of variable `t` is an integer and not a string.

`range(len(text))` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

When you are iterating over `range(len(text))`, value of `t` is an integer and this value is used to perform the `not in` check, hence the error.

You can instead iterate over the `text` instead of `range(len(text))`.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    av=[]
    for t in text:
        if t not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            av.append(t)
    print "".join(av)

anti_vowel("Hey You!")
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do `range(len(text))` you are constructing a range over the length of the input string, text. So the values of `t` are the integers `0, 1, 2... len(text)-2, len(text)-1`.

What you probably want to do is loop over the characters in the string itself:

```
for t in text:
    if t not in "aeiouAEIOU":
      av.append(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 4, there should be character `text[t]` instead of the numeric index `t`. That will fix your code.

The Python can deal with the indices for you.
The whole function can be then written in just one easy to read line:

```
print "".join(ch for ch in text if ch not in 'aeiouAEIOU')
```